# MS Access SQL to select random destination for each user

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have the following tables in MS Access 2007:

[image: Users Table]

[image: Destinations Table]

[image: Many-to-Many Relationship Table]

The relationship table determines which destinations are allowed for each user. At the moment each user is able to go to any destination but this may not be the case in the future.

I want to be able to use a SQL query to select a random destination for each user.

The result of the SQL query would look something like this:

[image: Results]

At the moment I have the following query which randomises the destinations:
SELECT userID, destinationID
FROM Relationship
ORDER BY userID, rnd(destinationID);

which gives this result:

[image: Current Query Result]

But I can't work out how to pick out just one random destination for each user ID.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you save your query

```
SELECT userID, destinationID FROM Relationship ORDER BY userID, rnd(destinationID)
```

as Q1, you can get the first (random) destination per user as:

```
SELECT userID, first(destinationID) from Q1 group by userID
```